# Crear un filtro para sorteo con sql en Postgrest

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql

Estoy deseando sortear personas que compraron en un supermercado. Las condiciones son que formen parte de los registros del super (en este caso sería la tabla `good_deal`) y que no sean empleados de la misma (tabla `empleados`).

Aunque al principio me pareció algo sencillo de hacer, lo cierto es que cada vez que sorteo unas veinte personas, uno o dos de ellos terminan formando parte de la tabla empleados.

Comparto el codigo de la consulta que utilicé la última vez:

```
SELECT  v.nro_ticket,
        v.fecha_venta,
        v.nombre_cliente,
        v.ci_nro,                       
        g.ci_good_deal, 
        v.ruc,              
        g.telefono_good_deal as telefono,
    v.total_venta,                          
        v.ticket_file,
    v.good_deal,       
        v.sucursal          

FROM  ventas v

INNER JOIN good_deal g

ON v.ci_nro = g.ci_good_deal          

INNER JOIN empleados e

ON g.ci_good_deal != e.ci   

WHERE v.nombre_cliente IS NOT NULL 

     and g.ci_good_deal IS NOT NULL 

     and g.ci_good_deal != ''

     and g.telefono_good_deal IS NOT NULL               

     and g.telefono_good_deal != ''              

     and g.ci_good_deal != '1111111'

 ORDER BY random() limit 1
```

Tabla "GOOD DEAL"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla "EMPLEADOS"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La tabla empleados tiene alguna columna que ayude a identificar que lo son?

Comment: Basándonos en [ask], considera por favor agregar la estructura de tus tablas